# How to edit file in nested archive

Tags: archive-mode

I have the following archive structure:

```
archive.zip
├── .ebextensions/
│   └── config.config
├── Dockerfile
└── target/
    └──jar.jar
```

With emacs I can open and edit the archive files, and also "enter" inside and edit the `jar.jar` archive, save those changes and seemingly update the jar, but I then cannot update `archive.zip` with the modified jar. Is it possible?